# Maintain two parallel git branches that share patches

Tags: git

I need to maintain two git branches of an open source project. The first branch `official` is basically a clone of the official repo. The second branch `custom` contains some custom patches. Some of those patches have been merged into the official repo. How do I keep `custom` upto date with the official repo while not causing conflicts ?

Answer (score 0):

If `custom` is not published (say, the commits in `custom` that don't appear in `official` aren't pushed to any other repository), you can `git fetch` and then `git rebase official` in order to get your commits applied on top of the `official` branch.

If that doesn't work for you, you can always `pull` `official` into `custom`, generating merge commits whenever you update your branch.